# Python can't find module when using interpreter

Tags: python, windows

When writing a program, I like to use the interpreter first to execute my code line by line. However, when using the interpreter, it can never seem to find modules that are definitely installed.

There is no issue when running a .py file. It's only when using the interpreter. My only solution is to change directory to where the module resides, but this is just so time consuming.

What could be the issue here? I wouldn't be anything to do with permissions as it works fine when run with a .py file. Not sure if it's a path environment issue, because again the issue is only when executed in the interpreter. It's very weird.

Comment: What interpreter are you using?

Comment: Hi, please provide more details about your situation, such as: What is your environment, e.g. your OS, python version, etc. How you use your interpreter (provide your command and other information).

Comment: Python 3.9.11 (main, Mar 18 2022, 16:54:01)  [GCC 11.2.0 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Comment: OS is Windows 10. I just call 'python' from the command prompt. I have selenium installed but executing 'from selenium import webdriver' calls back a NoModuleFound error.

Comment: Sorry, I mean 'ModuleNotFoundError'.

Comment: It sounds like you have ore than one python installed. `sys.executable` will tell you which one you are using. Try printing it in the working and failing cases.

Comment: And to be clear, when you say "change directory" are you for instance changing to the directory with selenium in it? What is that directory?

Comment: I just change my directory to 'site-packages' and then I can import the modules

Comment: Ah! sys.executable from running in python interpreter in CMD outputted this. C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\python.exe. This seems to be the issue....

Comment: I don't want to remove 'C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\' from the environment variable though because I use mingw64 to compile C++ programs. How can I make it execute my standard python instead rather than the one in 'C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\'?

Comment: Thank you very much. I moved original python location up so it is before mingw on the list in environment variables. That has resolved the issue :)

Comment: That's not an easy one to answer. I'm not sure which environment variable you are referring to, but generally, you want a "system" python - the one you use daily (on a linux platform that would be the one installed by the OS install) and then have alternate environments as needed. For a C++ build, you would have a batch or powershell file that setup the environment it needed. You could also have a python virtual environment where you install task specific python modules. But there are other ways to do it too.

Comment: Another option is to install selenium and other modules into multiple environments. `python -m pip install selenium` would put it in the right place.

Answer (score -2):

Try installing an older version of python and then see if you get the same error. It worked for me when I had the same error.

Comment: Yes and no. OP may want multiple python versions and will end up juggling among them.

Comment: NO. Delete the newer version and install the 2nd or 3rd older version prior to it.

Comment: What? Its okay to have multiple pythons in your system. That's just silly.

Comment: I told you to delete the newer version.

Comment: Why? I have 4 versions of python on my machine right now. And you could add in a half dozen virtual environments that have a different mix of modules installed. Its normal and easily manageable. You are giving bad advise.